# updating existing image with new image

Tags: php, mysql, css, html

im new to php and i want to update a logo, i mean i want to upload an image file which i want to be replaced by the logo.png and shown as a logo on my webpage, the code till now is uploading an image and saving the image in the folder but not replacing the exixting image with the new one, olease help me solve this problem, thanku

this is     setup.php

```
<?php include("../includes/config.php"); ?>
<?php
 if ($_SESSION["isadmin"])
{

$con=mysql_connect($dbserver,$dbusername,$dbpassword);
if (!$con) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }

mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);

 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM setup WHERE (id=".$_SESSION["id"].")");
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
   $title = $row['title'];
   $theme = $row['theme'];
 }
mysql_close($con);
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Admdin Home</title>
<link rel="StyleSheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
</head>
<body>
<?php include("includes/header.php"); ?>
<?php include("includes/nav.php"); ?>
<?php include("includes/aside.php"); ?>
<div id="maincontent">

  <div id="breadcrumbs">
    <a href="">Home</a> >
    <a href="">Setup</a> >
    Customization
 </div>
 <h2>Customize</h2>
 <?php
if (isset($_GET["status"]))
{
 if($_GET["status"]==1)
{
echo("<strong>Customization Done!</strong>");
}
if($_GET["status"]==2)
{
 echo("<strong>Customization Error!!</strong>");
}
}

?>
<form method="post"  action="setup-action.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<label>Title Of Your Organization:</label>  <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php    echo $title; ?>" /> <br /> <br />
<label>Select Theme</label>
<select name="theme" value="<?php echo $theme; ?>">
 <option value="Default">Default</option>
<option value="Dark">Dark</option>
<option value="White">White</option>
</select>
 <br /> <br />
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="Upload" value="Upload" />
</form>
</div>

</body>
 <?php include("includes/footer.php"); ?>
</html>
<?php
 }
 else
 {
    header("Location: ".$fullpath."login/unauthorized.php");

 }
?>
```

this is      setup-action.php

```
    <?php include("../includes/config.php");?>
<?php
$target_path = "../graphics/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path))
{
   echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']).
 " has been uploaded";
}
else
{
echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
<?php
$title=$_POST["title"];
$theme=$_POST["theme"];
$con=mysql_connect($dbserver,$dbusername,$dbpassword);
if (!$con) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }

mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM setup WHERE id=".$_SESSION['id']);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($num_rows > 0)
{
{
mysql_query("UPDATE setup  SET title='".$title."' , theme='".$theme."'WHERE    id=".$_SESSION['id']);
 header("Location:setup.php?status=1");
}
}
else {
 header("Location:setup.php?status=2");
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at **[PHP File Upload Tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php)**. You may use `logo.png` as the file name.

Comment: how can i get image overwriting when uploading? and if uploading an image titeld different how can i make it to change to specific file tite?im trying to make an image replacement to change image on the web page like for example logo. (iam not storing any image in the database,it would just place one image at a time in the graphics folder)

how can i make the file name change to the one i already uploaded lets say i have logo.jpg and i uploaded logo444.jpg how can i force it to rename to logo.jpg?

Comment: use `$target_path = "uploads/logo.jpg";` and remove the line `$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);`